# Antrl V4 Editor / interactive interpreter?

Tags: python

I am new to Antrl and googling around looking for good editor/test environment for Antrl v4, i found none.

the only environment i found is AntrlWorks1.x which is powerfull but doesn't support Antrl v4 or Antrlworks2.x that does support but lacks the interactive interpreter (test environment).

Is there another tool i missed?

Comment: I know that this is not Stack Overflow, but  http://www.antlr.org/support.html says "Please do not start discussions at stackoverflow. They have asked us to steer discussions (i.e., non-questions/answers) away from Stackoverflow; we have a discussion forum at Google specifically for that:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/antlr-discussion ", so you might want to ask there.